# Big javascript needs to be loaded and transformed in xml object

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, string

I have a js script which has only one variable, but that variable holds a 20 MB String. I need to load that script so i can transform that String Into an XML object, so i can emulate offline search on a website.

I need ideas on how to accomplish this.
First, I must probably wait the js script to be loaded. I don't know how to do that, i tried with jQuery and i did not succeed.

Comment: Holding 20 MB String is bad approach. This may case to crash browser /non responsive

Comment: I have a database which i transform in an xml, but because i can't read xml file locally i need to save it as a string so i can transform it in a xml object so i can perform search on it. I know is bad approach, it's horrible, but right now i can't see a better solution. I done this in the past, but i had smaller strings, a lot smaller. And it worked very well. But now ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OPTION 1:

- break the 20 MB into 1 MB (or even 512 KB) chunks.
- enumerate those chunks -- i.e. give them numbers 1,2,3 -- to identify their order
- then load them in parallel ajax requests -- may be 3-4 parallel requests (or more?)
- once all are downloaded to the browser -- join'em -- and you've got your 20 MB text ready

OPTION 2:

use flash -- you can do better ajax with it (if i am not wrong) and it will also tell you the loading status

OPTION 3:

in HTML 5 browsers you might use WebSockets. and gracefully degrade in older clients

Comment: Can't use flash, can't use Html5 cause it must work on all browsers. I will probably try your option 1. Thanks Greengit